# Window won't close when "no" is entered? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me find the mistakes in my code? The window won't close when "no" is entered after finishing a game and I just can't seem to find the mistake.
For context: I was trying to make a battleship game and to make it interactive with javascript. When the ship is hit the user is supposed to have the option to play again (the window reloads just fine) and if the user decides that he doesn't want to play anymore he just has to enter "no" and the window closes but that doesn't work for some reason. I can't seem to find the mistake no matter what I do. Does anyone more experienced have an idea?

```
var table = document.getElementById("buttons");

var len_board = document.getElementsByClassName("tr").length;

var button = document.getElementsByClassName("location")

//Places ships on the board randomly
function placeShips(len_board) {
   window.random_row = Math.floor(Math.random() * (len_board - 1)) + 1;
   window.random_column = Math.floor(Math.random() * (len_board - 1)) + 1;
};


//Save users choice and determine if ship is hit
function  getId(element) {
   var chosen_row = element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex
   var chosen_column = element.parentNode.cellIndex

   if ((random_row == chosen_row) && (random_column == chosen_column)) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        element.style.borderColor = 'red';
        element.textContent = "X";
        alert("you hit my ship");
        var answer = prompt("Would you like to play again? Enter 'Yes' for 
        yes and 'No' for no:");
        var answer = answer.toLowerCase();
        if (answer == "yes") {
            location = location;
        }

        else if (answer == "no") {  
            window.close();
        }

        else {
            var reply = prompt("I'm sorry, " + answer + " is not a valid 
            input. Please try again: ");
            var reply = reply.toLowerCase();
            if (reply == "no") {
                window.close();
            }
            else if (answer == "yes") {
                location = location;
            }
            else {
                window.close();
            };
        };
   }

   else {
      element.style.backgroundColor = "#a9c8f9";
      element.style.borderColor = "#a9c8f9";
   };
};
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close#Closing_the_current_window

Comment: I fixed it. It works just fine now that I changed window.close() to self.close()

Answer (score 0):

A script can only close a window that was opened by the script. You can't close the main window that loaded the script.

Answer (score 0):

[Window.close() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)

> This method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened
>   by a script using the window.open() method. If the window was not
>   opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the
>   console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.

This was done for security reasons. I'm sure you wouldn't like it if you were browsing the web and all of a sudden your window closed along with all the back history after clicking on a random link from a reddit post.

> ### Closing the current window
>
> In the past, when you called the window object's close() method
>   directly, rather than calling close() on a window instance, the
>   browser closed the frontmost window, whether your script created that
>   window or not. This is no longer the case; for security reasons,
>   scripts are no longer allowed to close windows they didn't open.
>   (Firefox 46.0.1: scripts can not close windows, they had not opened)

Comment: it worked fine before though, then I added the else if statements and it didn't work anymore. Do you know any other way I could close the window?